# After a CMS with no front end that simply spits out XML

Tags: xml, content-management-system, enterprise

There seem to be some similar - but not identical - questions out there, and having reviewed them, it still seems worth asking, so here goes.

I'm looking into Content Management Systems for a client. For various reasons their needs are complex, and there are likely to be several different web sites, all hosted on different platforms, using different technologies, in different network locations, all of which need to consume the same content in real time.

To that end a typical solution with close front end integration is out of the question. I need something with a slick, polished administration interface, with all the typical CMS features one might find - templates, support for structured data (customers, orders, etc), workflow, revision control/rollback - that simply spits out its content as XML over HTTP (either SOAP, or just a RESTful pseudo-web service; that kind of thing).

So in an ideal world we'd be able to edit a page called 'Innotech Inc', which might use a template called 'CASE_STUDY', and then I could expose a URL like:

http://foo.bar/get/page/innotech_inc

... which would give me that page as XML. My web sites, be they written in J2EE, .NET, PHP, and be they traditional web sites, or iPad apps, or Android apps, or whatever, could all just merrily parse that XML and do whatever the heck they want with it.

Maybe I could also call something like

http://foo.bar/get/page/templateid=CASE_STUDY

... which would give me all pages using the template 'case study' in abstract, which I could then drill down to see as I wish. Again, using XML. Nothing but sweet XML.

The closest I've found so far is Magnolia but even this seems like more of a case of using a small subset of something in order to do something else. Is there anything else out there more suited?

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Would a content repository like midgard work? http://www.midgard-project.org/

Answer (score 0):

take a look at : http://symphony-cms.com/